# Do apps require permission to open camera and gallery

Tags: android, permissions

I used to think that to access the camera and gallery from your application, permission is required and specifically in Marshmallow or above permission are required at runtime

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But I think I was wrong because my app is working without permission also. I have Myapp -> permission. No permission is granted. **But how can it work**. Below is my simple code for gallery  :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        takePhoto ( );
    }

    public void takePhoto ( ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent ( );
        intent.setType ( "image/*" );
        intent.setAction ( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );//
        startActivityForResult ( Intent.createChooser ( intent, "Select Image" ), SELECT_IMAGE );
    }

    public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        super.onActivityResult ( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        if ( requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE ) {
            if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                if ( data != null ) {
                    try {
                        Log.e ( "INSIDE------", "onActivityResult: " );
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap ( this.getContentResolver ( ), data.getData ( ) );

                    } catch ( IOException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace ( );
                    }

                }
            } else if ( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
                Toast.makeText ( this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ( );
            }
        }
    }
```

and for camera this is the code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        takePhoto (  );
    }
    public void takePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
```

**My manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.utkarshshukla.fragmentpractice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**my gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.utkarshshukla.fragmentpractice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Both of the code works , I haven't declared any permission in manifest. Though after declaring permission in manifest for camera it got crashed saying permission required but without writing in manifest it works  why it works (not tried same for gallery).In developers site they have mentioned to take permission but didn't mention what will happen if no permission taken.
***Question is why it is working without permissions***

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Consider Using an Intent training](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes.html#perms-vs-intents):

> In many cases, you can choose between two ways for your app to perform a task. You can have your app ask for permission to perform the operation itself. Alternatively, you can have the app use an intent to have another app perform the task.

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` are both examples of using an `Intent` to ask another app or the system to provide content to your app without requiring any runtime permissions. Therefore there are no runtime permissions required for these operations.

Comment: can you give an example how to use camera without intent that is without requiring other app to do it and doing the work through our app only .

Comment: @UtkarshShukla - you'd want to follow the [Building a camera app training](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)